# How to filter out unnecessary fields (nested fields) in returned records

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, pymongo

How could I only  show the fields `table_name` and `data` with year `2013`, `2014`

Records contain lots of fields,

`_id`, `table_name`, `unit`, ..., `schedule_id`

How could I only  show the fields `table_name` and `data` with year `2013`, `2014`, I want to know how to do it with Pymongo, mongoDB, and Mongoid

To  more specific I want the record returns in the following format.

## Original

```
{
  "_id": "2012-04-25_pce_inflation",
  "table_name": "pce_inflation",
  "unit": "Percent",
  "data": {
    "2012": {
      "number_of_participants": "3"
    },
    "2013": {
      "number_of_participants": "3"
    },
    "2014": {
      "number_of_participants": "7"
    },
    "2015": {
      "number_of_participants": "4"
    }
  },
  "end_date": new Date("2012-04-25T08:00:00+0800"),
  "updated_at": new Date(1426741272196),
  "created_at": new Date(1426741272195),
  "schedule_id": "2012-04-25"
}
```

## Expected

```
{
  "table_name": "pce_inflation",

  "data": {
    "2013": {
      "number_of_participants": "3"
    },
    "2014": {
      "number_of_participants": "7"
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: @muistooshort Both. I can use PyMongo or Mongoid on  my project, I'm glad to see any advice on therm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called a [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

Instead of a driver-specific solution, here is the general approach.

For example, your normal query in mongo shell as:

`db.coll.find({"table_name": "pce_inflation"})`

And you now want to get rid of the `_id` field, your query will become:

`db.coll.find({"table_name": "pce_inflation"}, {"_id":0 , "table_name":1, "data.2013":1, "data.2014":1})`

The syntax of the projection is specified in the above link

> < field>: <1 or true> Specify the inclusion of a field.
>
> < field>: <0 or false>    Specify the suppression of the field.