# How could I filter old_collection and insert the filtered data into new_collection using quick way

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, pymongo

I need to filter the **old_collection** into **new one**.

Now,I can do it with **Ruby** , but it's too slow doing this on application level, but I don't know how to do this kind of action in **native mongoDB query**

And my collection size is over **billions**, so that might be have **oversize issue**  easily. (document size 16MB limitation)

The **old_collection** is to record customer's order,

**new_collection** is to aggregate customers orders.

## Order

```
order_id : <ID OF THIS RECORD>
customer_name : <NAME OF THE CUSTOMER>
customer_birthday : <AGE OF THE CUSTOMER>
buy_items : <ARRAY_OF_ITEM_NAMES>
date : <BUY_DATE>
```

## User

```
customer_name,
customer_birthday,
buy_items_history : [{items: buy_items, date: buy_date, id: order_id}, ....]
uniq_buy_items, # only stored buy items
```

## Sample example

## data source : orders

```
{
    order_id : 1
    customer_name : Jack
    customer_birthday : 1987-06-12
    buy_items : ["ruby cookbook", "python cookbook", "mongodb cookbook"]
    date : 2011-01-15
},
...
{
    order_id : 13
    customer_name : Jack
    customer_birthday : 1987-06-12
    buy_items : ["Java cookbook", "mongodb cookbook"]
    date : 2015-04-15
}
```

## expected result

```
{
    customer_name : Jack
    customer_birthday : 1987-06-12
    buy_items_history: [{items: ["ruby cookbook", "python cookbook", "mongodb cookbook"],date: 2011-01-15, id:1]},
                        {items: ["Java cookbook", "mongodb cookbook"],date: 2015-04-15, id:13]},
                       ]
    uniq_buy_items : ["Java cookbook", "ruby cookbook", "python cookbook", "mongodb cookbook"]
}
```

### UPDATE

This is my current code, but it runs to slowly, I want to know how to do it quickly.

I need an idea how to manipulate data among collections  `find_or_create_by`

Any idea or better keywords for searching the find of question ?

```
module  CreateCustomersHelper
  def add_record_to_Customer_history(record)
      Customer = get_Customer(record)
      items.each do |item|
        Customer.add_to_set(uniq_buy_items: item)
      end
      Customer.add_to_set(buy_items_history: new_history_item(record))
      Customer.save
  end

  private
    def get_Customer(r)
      Customer.find_or_create_by(id: r["ID"])
    end

    def new_history_item(r)
      { 
        ...
      }      
    end

end
```

Comment: Based on a bunch of your previous Mongodb questions ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29444338/1090562), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29405745/1090562), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29250081/1090562), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29223621/1090562) ), it looks like you use SO as a free coding service: posting the requirements and expecting someone to write the code for you. SO has another purpose (helping with problems).

Comment: Hi @Dali , I think most users are asking their question for their coding  problem, I don't need someone to  write a code for me, instead , I need a idea or sample similar code to fix my problem.

Comment: yes, people ask questions about their real problems. But it makes a big difference how the is a question asked. Your previous question looked like: `I have requirements, write the code I can paste`. If you look at your first version you will see that it is `do my work for me` kind of question. On the other side your current question clearly shows what have you tried and why you are not satisfied with you success (which makes it better). With your previous question someone would spend time and may be end up with something that you already have, just to hear from you `I tried and do not like it`

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, I did not mean it, I will attention on it next time. For this question, I know how to do it with ruby , but it's too slow doing this on this application level, but i don't know how to do this kind of action in native mongoDB query.

Comment: From your comments, I see that you did not mean it and I am sure you will make your questions way better next time (I already saw a progress). English was not a problem (I understood what is your problem after the second iteration). Good luck with your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Following mongo aggregation will get the expected results

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$customer_name",
    "birthDay": {
        "$first": "$customer_birthday"
    },
    "buy_items_history": {
        "$push": {
            "items": "$buy_items",
            "date": "$date",
            "id": "$_id"
        }
    },
    "unique": {
        "$push": "$buy_items"
    }
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$unique"  // Unwind twice because "unique" is now an array of arrays
}, {
    "$unwind": "$unique"
}, {  // Now use $addToSet to get the distinct values     
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "birthDay": {
        "$first": "$birthDay"
    },
    "buy_items_history": {
        "$first": "$buy_items_history"
    },
    "uniq_buy_items": {
        "$addToSet": "$unique"
    }
    }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: thanks for your sharing, I will try it, and hope it will run quick than Ruby version